# Have make command exit 1

Tags: makefile, exit-code

I'm trying to throw an error with Make command. This is my makefile:

```
exit:
    val=1
    exit $(val)
```

However, when I run `make exit && echo $?` it gave me exit code 0. I was expecting exit code 1.

Did I use it wrong? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Makefile target "scripts" are not run like real scripts, instead each command is run in a separate *shell*.
2. You need to escape dollar signs in makefiles by using an extra dollar sign.
3. There is a fundamental difference between makefile variables, declared outside of targets and referenced using `$(name)`, and shell variables, declared as part of a command inside a target and referenced using `$${name}`.

What you want is either a single command equivalent to `val=1 && exit $val`:

```
exit:
    val=1 && exit $${val}
```

or a makefile variable used in a simple command:

```
val = 1
exit:
    exit $(val)
```

Comment: If I use the makefile variable, can I reassign/update it inside exit?

Comment: For example: ```val=0
exit:
 val=1
 exit $(val)```

Comment: Mixing makefile and shell variables is a bad idea, and probably won't work the way you expect. But give it a try if you want. You might want to post the resulting makefile to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to get some feedback.